# what is the simplest way to make christmas tree using 'for'?

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to print

```
+
+++
+++++
+++++++
+++++++++
```

in the easiest way using 'for'.
similarly,

```
#
 #
  #
   #
    #
     #
```

I want to print this in similar structure with code above

what I tried :

```
for(i in 1:5){
  cat(("*"*i), "/n")
}
```

but it's wrong because it's non-numeric argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there! just change `cat(("*"*i), "/n")` to `cat(rep("+", i), "\n")`. Use `rep` and use `\` instead of `/`.

```
> for(i in 1:5) {
    cat(rep("+", i), "\n")
    }
+ 
+ + 
+ + + 
+ + + + 
+ + + + +
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rep`

```
for(i in 1:5){
print(rep('*', i), quote=FALSE)
}
```